# adding tab in action bar with navigation drawer in material design

Tags: java, android, xml, navigation-drawer, material-design

i am new in material concept so as am stuck with some lack of knowledge. Kindly help me out with the problem am running threw currently.

MAINACTIVITY

```
package com.sample.mpassbook.mpassbook_d;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {


    private Toolbar mtoolbar;
    private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;
    ViewPager pager;
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    SlidingTabLayout tabs;
    CharSequence Titles[]={"CURRENT","DEBIT","CREDIT"};
    int Numboftabs =3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mtoolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        if (mtoolbar != null) {
            mtoolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            setSupportActionBar(mtoolbar);
//            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

        drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mtoolbar);
        drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);



     Transactionfragment fragment = new Transactionfragment();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager(); //or getFragmentManager() if you are not using support library.
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
        ft.commit();




    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);

        // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
        tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

        // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
        tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
            }
        });

        // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
//
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

//        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
//        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
//            return true;
//        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
        displayView(position);
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new Transactionfragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_transaction);
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new Settingsfragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_settings);
                break;
//            case 2:
//                fragment = new MessagesFragment();
//                title = getString(R.string.title_messages);
//                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            // set the toolbar title
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        }
    }


}
```

Activity_layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
        <com.sample.mpassbook.mpassbook_d.SlidingTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

    </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.sample.mpassbook.mpassbook_d.FragmentDrawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here my navigation drawer intent was working fine while but after adding tabs to the actionbar i cant intent to other pages from navigation bar.
For example: if i click navigation bar and select "settings" tab it's not directing to settings layout. Kindly give better suggestions so as it helps me out in future.